# Regular expression for "not in a list of values" without negative lookahead

Tags: python, regex

I want to search for a string that doesn't exist in a list of strings by using regex. Is it possible to make a regex for that case **without** using **negative lookahead**?

Comment: Which language is this in?

Comment: I am using python and django and i want to send the query to MySQL.

Comment: You could use negative lookbehind...

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense to me. Can you show an example of the string you are searching for and the list you are searching in, plus whatever you have already tried that doesn't work.

Comment: Actually I managed to do what i needed by using django's Q objects. I wanted to create an OR query in django, with the 2nd operand to be a NOT AND logic. I thought that I could do that only by using regex. I was mistaken. Thank you all.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the regular expression for "in a list of values", and return `False` if there's a match.

Answer (score 1):

When you just search for a plain string in a list of strings you don't even need regex. you can just do `string not in list_of_strings`

For example if you have

```
list_of_string = ['string1', 'string2', 'string3']
string = 'string4'
```

`string not in list_of_strings` would result in `True`